# database seeder with File facade not working on deploy

Tags: php, laravel, database

When seeding the data locally I have no problems, the information is seeded to the database, but when deploying to Forge they don't show up, I suspect it is something to do with the File facade, or something with different permissions now its on the serve, but I am not sure were to go from here.

```
<?php

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{

    private function seedFrontpageConfigurations(array $folders, string $type)
    {
        foreach ($folders as $key => $folder) {
            $folderPath = public_path('assets/configuration_thumbnails/' . $type . '/' . $folder);
            $filesInFolder = File::files($folderPath);

            foreach ($filesInFolder as $file) {
                $fileName = basename($file);
                $filePath = asset(str_replace('\\', '/', $file->getPathname()));

                $frontpageConfiguration = new FrontpageConfiguration();
                $frontpageConfiguration->url = $filePath;
                $frontpageConfiguration->identifier = $fileName;
                $frontpageConfiguration->size = $folder;
                $frontpageConfiguration->type = $type;
                $frontpageConfiguration->save();
            }
        }
    }

    public function run()
    {
        $type = "dawn";
        $folders = ['2seater', '2seater', '3seater', 'corner'];
        $this->seedFrontpageConfigurations($folders, $type);
    }
}
```